# Calculate sum of area (populated as one the fields in attribute table) and store in a different table with filename information

Tags: python, raster, arcgis, arcpy

I have more than 200000 raster files, for which, each file contains the day-month-year information of that particular file. All of these files have a column with area, and I need sum of that area to be stored along with the day/month/year information. The file looks like this : asi-s3125-20030928-v5.4.tif , where 20030928 is my YYYYMMD (Year Mon Date). Now, each file has several rows of pixels with areal information - I need sum of that area to be stored in an excel/table with the YYYYMMD information.

What I tried:

```
raster_folder = "C:RSP_New/Clipped/Xtras"
... output_folder = "C:/RSP_New/Clipped/Xtras"
... output_name = "AreaSumByDay"
... 
... # create the output table
... table = arcpy.management.CreateTable(output_folder, output_name)
... arcpy.management.AddField(table, "Day", "TEXT")
... arcpy.management.AddField(table, "SumArea", "FLOAT")
... 
... # start inserting values
... with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(table, ["Day", "SumArea"]) as cursor:
...     # loop over the rasters in the folder
...     arcpy.env.workspace = raster_folder
...     for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():
...         name = raster.split(".")[0]
...         day = name.split("-")[-2]
...         # get the sum of the area field
...         raster_obj = arcpy.Raster(raster_folder + "/" + raster)
...         sum_area = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(raster_obj).sum()
...         # write into the table
...         cursor.insertRow([day, sum_area])
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

---

I have tested this multiple ways, but seems like the table is generated, but empty.

I get the following system error (first screenshot/image), also the table is created with the name area_sum_of_day, yet looks empty  (like the second screenshot).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5kLi.png)
[Main error: System Error as mentioned]
My file names are in style: asi-s3125-20030928-v5.4.tif or asi-AMSR2-s3125-20130101-v5.4.tif.

I want to split it around 10th character "asi-s3125-" in the first case and use 7 characters from there for the filename. Can you please provide me what is going wrong, it would save lots of time as there's heaps of data, and I have been spending a lot of time understanding these already.

I'm trying to currently test in Arcpy, but I welcome options from QGIS as well if that's got better options.
Any help would be highly appreciated and greatly obliged

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the solution you have written which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Exactly how are you running this?  Your error message doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: And you can use `filename.split('-')[-2]` to extract the date/time from your filenames.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm running in python command window in arcpy. That's how my other small snippets worked. Is it not the right way? Can you suggest alternatives please. Also, the table is generated, but is all empty.

Comment: If you do a `print` in that loop, do you see the correct data?

Comment: @TimRoberts I still get the error: "Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
SystemError: error return without exception set !!!

Comment: Another alternative is, I want to add the filename to my attribute table and possibly concatenate the attribute data into an Excel. Is that a possible option? But, again, for adding the filename to the attribute table, %name% in the arcmap_model does copy filename, whereas it doesn't work  while calculating fields